# We are three sisters. Who are we?

Tags: riddle

> We are three sisters.
>
> Our job is the same, but the way of work is different.
>
> We repeat our task  number of times.
>
> We help people do their work

Who are we?

Hint:

> We are use in programming

Comment: Some small grammatical corrections: "the way of work" --> "our way of working", "number" --> "a number", and "use" --> "used".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The 3 different loops:
>  The for-loop.
>  The while-loop.
>  The until-loop.

Comment: @lois6b it happened to me two times today.

Comment: i know. i've been here, i watched hahahaha lol. sorry.

Comment: @lois6b and the op was the same

Comment: Everything is a plot against you. You know it

Answer (score 15):

My guess would be

> The three hands of a watch / clock.
>
>  All three of them's work is to run around the clock, but they do it faster or slower.
>
> They obviously repeat their task number of times, by spinning until the watch eventually runs out of battery.
>
>  They help people to do their work by scheduling tasks and making people's work more efficient ([like this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pomodoro_Technique)).
>
>  finally they are "kind of" used in programming, as almost every random value generated in programming is done using a seed based on TIME (the entire time spent since January 1st, 1970, in seconds).

Comment: I was going to add this as answer before but changed when OP added a hint.

Answer (score 7):

Can be

> for, while, and foreach loop or do-while

Our job is the same, but the way of work is different.

> iteration, but in different way of course

We repeat our task number of times.

> they repeat the same task again and again.

We help people do their work

> not sure, but may be do some specific tasks repeatedly

Comment: What? And no goto:?

Comment: Goto is not a loop. is just a Jump statement. Can be used to make a loop but it would be like using a phone as a hammer.

Comment: @lois6b I would argue it is more like using a jackhammer as a hammer, it might get the job done, but its going to break everything around it.

Comment: All of these boil down to conditional jumps.  When they are converted to machine code, they all become exactly that.  Although "goto" is not conditional, why is a conditional jump not included?

Answer (score 6):

You are

> Compiler, Linker, and Interpreter

Our job is the same, but the way of work is different.

> The job of all three is to create an application. But the way of work is different since one compiles the source code, the other links it, and the third interprets it.

We repeat our task number of times.

> Each module is run several times over the source code to produce the application executable.

We help people do their work

> Each of these modules help programmers write runnable programs.